# Model selection: testing the need for random-effects terms in longitudinal data

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I have longitudinal data set where each participant was observed for 12 weeks.
I followed this paper: Bliese, Paul D., and Robert E. Ployhart. ["Growth modeling using random coefficient models: Model building, testing, and illustrations." Organizational Research Methods 5.4 (2002): 362-387](http://orm.sagepub.com/content/5/4/362.short).

First I fitted a generalized least squares model, which produces the following result:
**model1 <- gls(X ~ group*time, data = dataFrame)**

```
Coefficients:
                       Value   Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)        1.6933389 0.009814656 172.53167  0.0000
group0            -0.0586920 0.010610159  -5.53168  0.0000
time               0.0005821 0.000192112   3.02993  0.0024
group0:time       -0.0006525 0.000207683  -3.14177  0.0017
```

Then I fitted a random-intercept model:

**model2 <- lme(X ~ group*time, random = ~1|id, data = dataFrame)**

```
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.2067486 0.2744509

Fixed effects: X ~ group * time 
                       Value   Std.Error    DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)        1.6933389 0.023882981 44230 70.90149  0.0000
group0            -0.0586920 0.025818758   580 -2.27323  0.0234
time               0.0005821 0.000153538 44230  3.79115  0.0002
group0:time       -0.0006525 0.000165983 44230 -3.93109  0.0001
```

The fixed part is almost identical to `model1`, apart from the standard error associated with `intercept` and `group0`.

Then I did a likelihood ratio test in order to choose a model,; it shows that the two models are significantly different.

**anova(model1, model2)**

```
Model      df      AIC      BIC     logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
model1     1  5 31435.78 31479.33  -15712.890                        
model2     2  6 13555.15 13607.41  -6771.574 1 vs 2 17882.63  <.0001
```

I am a bit confused which model I should choose: if I consider standard errors they are a bit smaller in `model1`, but based on the likelihood ratio test should I choose the model with random intercepts?

**--Updated--**

**model3 <- lme(X ~ group*time, random = ~time|id, data = dataFrame)**

```
Random effects:
 Formula: ~time | id
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev      Corr  
(Intercept) 0.202541906 (Intr)
time        0.003067617 -0.317
Residual    0.265761977       

Fixed effects: X ~ group * time 
                       Value   Std.Error    DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)         1.6933389 0.023368045 44230 72.46387  0.0000
group0             -0.0586920 0.025262085   580 -2.32333  0.0205
time                0.0005821 0.000366240 44230  1.58935  0.1120
group0:time        -0.0006525 0.000395925 44230 -1.64802  0.0994
```

**anova(model1, model2, model3)**

```
 Model     df      AIC      BIC     logLik   Test   L.Ratio p-value
model1     1  5 31435.78 31479.33 -15712.890                         
model2     2  6 13555.15 13607.41  -6771.574 1 vs 2 17882.633  <.0001
model3     3  8 11689.56 11759.24  -5836.779 2 vs 3  1869.588  <.0001
```

Since I am interested in seeing the growth of the group effect the slopes are no longer significant. Should I still choose `model3`?

Comment: we need to see the results of `anova(model1, model2, model3)`

Comment: I have updated to include the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likelihood ratio test is slightly incorrect (in general, conservative) for testing the significance of a random effect, because the null value ($\sigma^2=0$) is at the boundary of the feasible space, but in this case there is *overwhelmingly* strong evidence against the null hypothesis. The model with random effects of individual is 15713-6772=8941 log-likelihood units better; twice the log-likelihood value is $\chi^2$ distributed, so the direct p-value calculation would give you ...

```
pchisq(2*8941,df=1,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)/log(10)
## -3885.251
```

... a p-value of approximately $10^{-3885}$.

You should really consider a random-slope model (`random = ~time|id`) as well.

**Update**: relative to the random-intercept model, the random-slopes model is again much better.  The improvement is now 935 log-likelihood units, which doing the equivalent calculation as above corresponds to a rejection of the null hypothesis (among-individual variation in slope is equal to zero) with a p-value of "only" $10^{-408}$.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have updated my question based on your suggestions. Is it still the case that I prefer random slope?

Comment: Thanks for the update. So that means I should not be bothered too much about the significance of slopes (group0*time and time)?

Comment: Correct. You should always do random-effects model selection (if you're going to do it in the first place) without regard to the estimates/significance of the fixed-effect parameters within the model.

Comment: if I require to explain and convince a layman that model3 is better choice  than model2 then how would I do it? Could you suggest in this regard?

Comment: what kind of layman? how much statistics do they know? (if they're arguing with you that you ought to choose the model with the strongest/most significant estimates for the fixed effects, I'm sorry, but they don't know what they're talking about ...) I'd probably draw some pictures of the data showing the estimated regression lines for the different groups.

Comment: Actually I am talking about myself I have been reading this stuff since month or so but I am a bit confused how to report these results specially after your suggestions. If you could provide me pointers to some references/papers?

Comment: I gave some reading suggestions recently at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214129/whats-the-interpretation-of-ranef-fixef-and-coef-in-mixed-effects-model-using ...